# Does this sentence miss “by”?

Tags: grammar

I read [a CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/05/21/us/texas-santa-fe-school-shooting/index.html) and I found the following sentence:

> "From what I see, I don't believe any of the individuals that were killed" were shot law enforcement during the crossfire with the suspect, Trochesset said.

I think it should be *shot **by** law enforcement*. But it’s hard for me to believe CNN made a mistake like this.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it should be "shot **by** law enforcement."

> But it’s hard for me to believe CNN made a mistake.

Journalists are churning out thousands of words per day. Occasionally small mistakes are to be expected.

Comment: Is it common that they make mistakes like this?

Comment: @user67265 It's not common. The typical newspaper article will not usually have a word missing like that.  However, it's not impossible.